# What are the new items on the first claim of US5147183?

Tags: us5147183

In reference to the patent: [US5147183](https://www.google.com/patents/US5147183)

There are many items on first claim about hydroulic pump. What are the new items on the first claim of US5147183?

Answer (score 1):

You can answer this for yourself. I'll briefly explain how to generally attack such a problem:

A patent description starts with a prior art description and the problem(s) to be solved:

> 2. Description of the Prior Art

Here the patent describes some general prior art and 3 patents (or applications) that are related. It should describe the most important similar items that are already known.

You can then compare these to the claims.

For further information, also on the evaluation of novelty and inventiveness by the examiner you can consult [US Public PAIR](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair). There is a prosecution history where documents sent by the applicant/attorney and the examiner are stored. This is a little more text than the first approach, but these documents normally explain exactly which elements are considered new and inventive by the examiner and which are not. Plus, somebody else did the work for you, you just have to read it. ;-)